# Convert csv to json multi-document?

Tags: python, json, csv

I have below two requirement using Python:

1. Convert csv to multi-document json.
2. Ignore "" or null objects.

Have mentioned both code and csv. Currently I am getting only json array objects but I need to create in multi-document json.

**my csv**

```
_id,riderDetails.0.category,riderDetails.0.code,riderDetails.1.category,riderDetails.1.code
1111,re,remg,er,error
2111,we,were,ty,
```

**code**

```
import csv
import json
def make_record(row):
    return  { 
    "_id" : row["_id"], 
    "riderDetails" : [
        {            
            "category" : row["riderDetails.0.category"], 
            "code" : row["riderDetails.0.code"],
        },
        {            
            "category" : row["riderDetails.1.category"] ,
            "code" : row["riderDetails.1.code"],
        }
    ]
}  


with open('N:/Exide/Mongo/rr22.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')

     with open('N:/Exide/Mongo/mm22.json', 'w') as jsonfile:       
       out = json.dumps([make_record(row) for row in reader])
       jsonfile.write(out)
```

**Code Output**

```
[{
    "_id": "1111",
    "riderDetails": [
        {
            "category": "re",
            "code": "remg"
        },
        {
            "category": "er",
            "code": "error"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "2111",
    "riderDetails": [
        {
            "category": "we",
            "code": "were"
        },
        {
            "category": "",
            "code": ""
        }
    ]
}]
```

**Expected Output**

```
{
    "_id": "1111",
    "riderDetails": [
        {
            "category": "re",
            "code": "remg"
        },
        {
            "category": "er",
            "code": "error"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id": "2111",
    "riderDetails": [
        {
            "category": "we",
            "code": "were"
        }
    ]
}
```

Can someone help me in achieving expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data in the **my csv** file in your question doesn't produce the output shown, but that's probably due to a minor posting error, so I'll ignore it.

Also note that the file you are producing isn't a strictly valid JSON format file — perhaps that's what you meant by the term "multi-document json"…

Regardless, you accomplish what you need by modifying the `make_record()` function so it "cleans-up" the record and removes any empty/missing values before it returns it.

This is done in two steps.

1. First go through from each detail in `riderDetails` and remove any keys that have empty values.
2. Lastly, go though each `riderDetails` again and remove any details that are completely empty (because the first step removed all of it contents or none were provided in the csv file being read).

```
import csv
import json

csv_inp = 'rr22.csv'
json_outp = 'mm22.json'

def make_record(row):
    # Reformat data is row.
    record = {
        "_id": row["_id"],
        "riderDetails": [
            {
                "category": row["riderDetails.0.category"],
                "code": row["riderDetails.0.code"],
            },
            {
                "category": row["riderDetails.1.category"],
                "code": row["riderDetails.1.code"],
            }
        ]
    }

    # Remove empty values from each riderDetail.
    record['riderDetails'] = [{key: value for key, value in riderDetail.items() if value}
                                for riderDetail in record['riderDetails']]

    # Remove completely empty riderDetails.
    record['riderDetails'] = [riderDetail for riderDetail in record['riderDetails']
                                if riderDetail]
    return record

with open(csv_inp, 'r', newline='') as csvfile, \
     open(json_outp, 'w') as jsonfile:

    for row in csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=','):
        jsonfile.write(json.dumps(make_record(row), indent=4) + '\n')
#        jsonfile.write(json.dumps(make_record(row)) + '\n')
```

Comment: Any idea of changing data types. currently all the attributes are generated as string type. How do i change to specific type eg. category to int

Comment: Yes — use something like `"category": int(row["riderDetails.0.category"]) if row["riderDetails.0.category"] else row["riderDetails.0.category"],`

Comment: Note also that the final `row["riderDetails.0.category"]` could be replaced with a possibly hardcoded default value, like `0` if you wished.

Comment: Hello @martineau your logic worked for my requirement. Now I want to replicate the below logic for object instead of array.           

 # Remove empty values from each riderDetail.
    record['riderDetails'] = [{key: value for key, value in riderDetail.items() if value}
                                for riderDetail in record['riderDetails']]

How do we remove empty for object

Comment: The `if value}` part of the dictionary comprehension should already allow only non-empty values to be put into the dictionary being created — so I'm not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

using glob

```
import glob, os

pt = 'N:/Exide/Mongo/*.csv'

for file in glob.glob(pt):
    get_name = file.split("/")[-1].replace(".csv",".json")
    with open(file , 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        out = [make_record(row) for row in reader]

    saving_path = os.path.join('N:/Exide/Mongo/',get_name)
    with open(saving_path , 'w') as jsonfile:       
        json.dump(out , jsonfile)
```

you get [{},{}] becuse you writing list of dictionary into file